# android arranging text view in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to have 3 text in layout. the `textView` in the center is red in color and the other 2 are black. so i added it to a `relativelayout` and set the `layout` as textView2 to the right of textView1 and textView3 to the right of textView2

[image: this is what i have done]

But when the text in the 3rd text view is bigger it should come textview one. insted I get this.

[image: when the 3rd text is longer i get this]

now what should i do to get somthing like this?

[image: this is what i need]

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rel_lay"
        android:background="#DFDFDF"
        android:padding="2dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="TextView when the third text is longer"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is the relative layout with 3 textView.

Comment: Do you want to give **Red** color to your 2nd textview? and other two black? If yes, I have solution for that with one textview you can achieve this.

Comment: @ChintanRathod how can i do that? 
text is passed from the java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one `TextView` and set text as per you need. You know which text to set for **Red** color. So what you need to have is *index of starting text* and *ending text*.

Use following code.

```
SpannableString spanText = new SpannableString("My Name is Chintan Rathod");
spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")), 5 /*start index*/, 10 /*end index*/, 0);
textView.setText(spanText);
```

Here, I have passed **5** and **10**, but you can pass your own indexes. But make sure *index* within range which will not fire **IndexOutOfBoundException**

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck with using [Spanned](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) classes and one TextView. The way you are trying to implement it, TextView #3 would have to fill_parent on the width *and* be able to know where TextView #2 ends.